# Zoom in zoom out

Tags: knowledge, visual, movies

[image]

A wall in a gallery hangs some paintings that look like a portion of the film's poster. And looking closer at the paintings some figures of characters are visible but blurred. Can you guess the titles of film posters and name the characters inserted on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial Answer: (31/40)

Movie / Character

1. > Lord of The Rings / Mario and Luigi
2. > Ghost (2019 movie) / Pacman
3. > Jurassic Park / Lightning McQueen and Mater (Cars movie)
4. > The Godfather / Teletubbies
5. > Gladiator / R2D2, C3PO and BB8 (Star Wars)
6. > The Schindler's List /Adolf Hitler
7. > Titanic / Mickey and Minnie Mouse
8. > Moonlight / Batman and Robin (?)
9. > ??? / Hercules and Megara
10. > ??? / ???
11. > Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (?) / Pinocchio
12. > ??? / Toph, Aang and Katara (Avatar series)
13. > Silence of the Lambs / Ronald McDonald
14. > ??? / Charlie Chaplin
15. > ??? / Wall-e and Eve
16. > The Hunt for Red October (?) / The Pink Panther
17. > ??? / Fender Pinwheeler  and Rodney Copperbottom (Robots movie)
18. > ??? / Tintin, Captain Haddock and  Professor Calculus
19. > The Sound of Music / The Beatles
20. > ??? / Finn (Adventure Time series)

Thanks @Prim3numbah for #3!

Comment: For #3 rot13(whenffvp cneg gur ybfg jbeyq)

Comment: only 3 movies not  won the best picture award

Answer (score 3):

Photo number 5:

> [Titanic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizyI-Yi4LtAhXixlkKHQNEA7QQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTitanic&usg=AOvVaw2Gb7cm4krVpxLmE1o5LxK2) Character: Titanic

Photo number 6:

> [Schindler's List](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj01aW-iYLtAhUErFkKHcx-BIsQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSchindler%2527s_List&usg=AOvVaw1d4snaRiytyDCABV9uK-OP) Characters:  Schindler and a young girl in a red coat