# Ten close-ups of popular video games

Tags: knowledge, visual, video-games

*Inspired by [Zoom in zoom out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104818/70545).*

Hello, I put together a gallery of abstract art:

[image]

Or this just displays what you would see if you were to wear binoculars in front of your X box!

**Find out what game does each of the ten close-ups belong to.**

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

---

1:

> Legend of Zelda? Ocarina of Time or Majora's Mask

2:

> Candy Crush

3:

> Super Mario Odyssey?

4:

> Super Smash Bros Ultimate? (Appears to be metal bowser)

5:

> Baraka from Mortal Kombat 11 (Thanks @George Menoutis )

6:

> 

7:

> Sonic: the Hedgehog

8:

> Minecraft

9:

> Among Us

10:

> Super Mario Bros.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out which installment of the series is shown in #10, it has to be the original - Mario isn't so blocky and doesn't wear brown in later games.

Comment: That's a lot of rot13(Znevbf) in your answer :D

Comment: 5 vf fheryl Onenxn sebz Zbegny Xbzong 11